# Automate the Boring Stuff with Python 2nd Edition - Chapter 8 - Sandwich Maker Project

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am learning Python through [Automate the Boring Stuff](https://automatetheboringstuff.com/2e/chapter8/#calibre_link-288). And I was trying to do the practice project Sandwich Maker in Chapter 8, although I somehow already solved the problem but I encountered some issue in the coding process. Here is my code:

```python
import pyinputplus as pyip

bread_type = { "Wheat":2.2,"White":1.2,"Sourdough":4.6}
protein_type = { "Chicken":3.3,"Turkey":5.9,"Ham":4.9,"Tofu":1.2}
cheese_type = { "Cheddar":2.2,"Swiss":1.2,"Mozzarella":4.6,"No cheese":0.0}
add_on_type = { "Mayo":1.0,"Mustard":0.8,"Lettuce":1.4,"Tomato":1.6,"No add-ons":0.0}

prompts=['What bread do you want?\n',
        'What protein do you want?\n',
        'Do you want cheese in your sandwich?\n',
        'What type of cheese do you want?\n'
        'Do you want some add ons to your sandwich?\n',
        'What add-ons do you want?\n',
        'How many of this sandwich do you want?\n']

def bread_order():
    prompt=prompts[0]
    bread_choice=bread_type.keys()
    return pyip.inputMenu(list(bread_choice),prompt=prompt,numbered=True)

def protein_order():
    prompt=prompts[1]
    protein_choice=protein_type.keys()
    return pyip.inputMenu(list(protein_choice),prompt=prompt,numbered=True)

def cheese_order():
    yes_no_prompt=prompts[2]
    prompt=prompts[3]
    cheese_choice=list(cheese_type.keys())
    yes_no_cheese=pyip.inputYesNo(prompt=yes_no_prompt)
    if yes_no_cheese=='no':
        return'No cheese'
    elif yes_no_cheese=='yes':
        return pyip.inputMenu(cheese_choice,prompt=prompt,numbered=True)

def add_ons_order():
    yes_no_prompt=prompts[4]
    prompt=prompts[5]
    add_ons_choice=list(add_on_type.keys())
    yes_no_add_ons=pyip.inputYesNo(prompt=yes_no_prompt)
    if yes_no_add_ons == 'No add_ons' :
        return 'No add-ons'
    elif yes_no_add_ons=='yes':
        return pyip.inputMenu(add_ons_choice,prompt=prompt,numbered=True)

def order_num():
    prompt=prompts[6]
    return pyip.inputInt(prompt)
    
choosed_bread=bread_order()
choosed_protein=protein_order()
choosed_cheese=cheese_order()
choosed_add_ons=add_ons_order()
ordered_num=order_num()

bread_price=bread_type[choosed_bread]
protein_price=protein_type[choosed_protein]
cheese_price=cheese_type[choosed_cheese]
add_on_price=add_on_type[choosed_add_ons]    
total_price = ordered_num*(bread_price+protein_price+cheese_price+add_on_price)

print("Order Summary:")
print('Bread type: %s \t %f', choosed_bread,bread_price)
print('Protein type: %s \t %f', choosed_protein,protein_price)
print('Cheese type: %s \t %f', choosed_cheese,cheese_price)
print('Add-on type: %s \t %f', choosed_add_ons,add_on_price)
print('Total price: \t %f', total_price)
```

However when I run the code until where it asks for cheese, the later prompt already appears(the bold line below).

```
What bread do you want?
1. Wheat
2. White
3. Sourdough
1
What protein do you want?
1. Chicken
2. Turkey
3. Ham
4. Tofu
1
Do you want cheese in your sandwich?
yes
What type of cheese do you want?
**Do you want some add ons to your sandwich?**
1. Cheddar
2. Swiss
3. Mozzarella
4. No cheese
```

I somehow avoid this problem by searching through the internet, learning from others code, but I am just curious why does this happens and how do I avoid this in the future? I believe this must be related to how Python actually runs, it might helps me in further understanding in Python as well.

Also, below are my current codes, I would like to have some feedbacks on how can I further improve on this code.

```python
import pyinputplus as pyip


def main():
    menu={'Bread':{"Wheat":2.2,"White":1.2,"Sourdough":4.6},
          'Protein':{"Chicken":3.3,"Turkey":5.9,"Ham":4.9,"Tofu":1.2},
          'Cheese':{"Cheddar":2.2,"Swiss":1.2,"Mozzarella":4.6,"No cheese":0.0},
          'Add_ons':{"Mayo":1.0,"Mustard":0.8,"Lettuce":1.4,"Tomato":1.6,"No add-ons":0.0}}
    prompts=['What bread do you want?\n',
            'What protein do you want?\n',
            ['Do you want cheese in your sandwich?(y/n)\n',
            'What type of cheese do you want?\n'],
            ['Do you want some add ons to your sandwich?(y/n)\n',
            'What add-ons do you want?\n'],
            'How many of this sandwich do you want?\n']
    menu_type_list=list(menu.keys())
    orders=[]
    for i in range(len(menu_type_list)):
        if i <= 1:
            orders.append(pyip.inputMenu(list(menu[menu_type_list[i]]),
                                         prompts[i],
                                         numbered='True'))
        elif i <= 3:
            if pyip.inputYesNo(prompt=prompts[i][0],yesVal='y',noVal='n')=='y' :
                orders.append(pyip.inputMenu(list(menu[menu_type_list[i]]),
                                             prompts[i][1],
                                             numbered='True'))
            else:
                orders.append(list(menu[menu_type_list[i]].keys())[-1])
    order_qty=pyip.inputInt(prompt=prompts[-1],default=1,greaterThan=0)
    total_price=0
    for i in range(len(orders)):
        total_price+=menu[menu_type_list[i]][orders[i]]
    print("Order Summary:")
    print(('Item type \t Items \t Price').expandtabs(15))
    for i in range(len(orders)):
        print(('%s type: \t %s \t %.2f' % 
               (menu_type_list[i],
                orders[i],
                menu[menu_type_list[i]][orders[i]]))
              .expandtabs(15))
    print('Number of sandwich: %d'%(order_qty))
    print(('Total price: \t \t %.2f' % (order_qty*total_price)).expandtabs(15))
    
if __name__ == '__main__' :
    main()
```

Thanks in advance! All help will be much appreciated!

Comment: _I would like to have some feedbacks on how can I further improve on this code_ is on-topic, but fixing the bug _the later prompt already appears_ is not.

Comment: Your question has been closed for this reason; but: with some edits it should fairly easily become on-topic. Redirect the focus to code review and then submit it for re-opening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a subtle bug.

```
prompts=[..., 'What type of cheese do you want?\n'        'Do you want some add ons to your sandwich?\n', ...]
```

Notice that a comma is missing - because of that, this is now a single (multiline) string, instead of two strings.
https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literal-concatenation

I'd highly recommend getting rid of `prompts` altogether. Either go for global constants:

```
PROMPT_BREAD = 'What bread do you want?\n'
...

def bread_order():
    bread_choice=bread_type.keys()
    return pyip.inputMenu(list(bread_choice),prompt=PROMPT_BREAD,numbered=True)
```

or for local ones:

```
def bread_order():
    prompt = 'What bread do you want?\n'
    bread_choice=bread_type.keys()
    return pyip.inputMenu(list(bread_choice),prompt=prompt,numbered=True)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I stuck on this problem for a few days in the end it was just a missing comma.